# Flutter: Link inside the webview opens to built in browser instead of the webview

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I have created a webview using flutter, i want to display a local webapp for now to my created webview.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class EnableJavacriptWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  EnableJavacriptWebViewState createState() {
    return new EnableJavacriptWebViewState();
  }
}

class EnableJavacriptWebViewState extends State<EnableJavacriptWebView> {
  bool _isJSEnabled = true;

  _onChanged() {
    setState(() {
      _isJSEnabled = !_isJSEnabled;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("TEST")),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://flutter.io/',
            javascriptMode: _isJSEnabled
                ? JavascriptMode.unrestricted
                : JavascriptMode.disabled,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but what happen is when i load the application(webview) it opens the Builtin browser instead of the inside webview application.

Answer (score 0):

Old Version of `flutter_webview_plugin` and `webview_flutter` was used in the `pubspec.yaml`
Should use latest version.